# Disjoint ranges in VHDL

Tags: arrays, range, vhdl, alias

I have a bit vector like this

```
subtype alarms_type : std_logic_vector(1 to 8)
signal alarms : alarms_type := (others => '0');
```

and the purpose of each bit is defined like this

```
constant sys1_temp_hi_al : integer := 1;
constant sys1_temp_lo_al : integer := 2;
constant sys1_crnt_hi_al : integer := 3;
constant sys1_cnrt_lo_al : integer := 4;
constant sys2_temp_hi_al : integer := 5;
constant sys2_temp_lo_al : integer := 6;
constant sys2_crnt_hi_al : integer := 7;
constant sys2_cnrt_lo_al : integer := 8;
```

I would like to be able to access subsets of the alarms_type with a short, readable notation. For example

```
alarms(SYS2_ALS) <= (others => '0');  -- set multiple values
temp_alarm <= or(alarms(TEMP_ALS));   -- or together multiple values to a std_logic
temp_alarms <= alarms(TEMP_ALS));     -- extract a subset to a suitably sized vector
alarms(TEMP_ALS) := (others => '1');  -- set (or clear) multiple disjoint values
```

I would like to know if the `alias` keyword will help me, like this:

```
alias HI_ALARMS is sys1_temp_hi_al|sys1_crnt_hi_al|sys2_temp_hi_al|sys2_crnt_hi_al;
alias LO_ALARMS is sys1_temp_lo_al|sys1_crnt_lo_al|sys2_temp_lo_al|sys2_crnt_lo_al;
alias TEMP_ALS  is sys1_temp_hi_al|sys1_temp_lo_al|sys2_temp_hi_al|sys2_temp_lo_al;
alias CRNT_ALS  is sys1_crnt_hi_al|sys1_crnt_lo_al|sys2_crnt_hi_al|sys2_crnt_lo_al;
alias SYS1_ALS  is sys1_temp_hi_al|sys1_crnt_hi_al|sys2_temp_hi_al|sys2_crnt_hi_al;
alias SYS2_ALS  is sys1_temp_hi_al|sys1_crnt_hi_al|sys2_temp_hi_al|sys2_crnt_hi_al;
```

It appears from the `Alias` chapter of the Ashenden book that this is not how an alias should be used, but hopefully I am missing something.

If there is a correct way to use `alias` to achieve my goal, please provide examples.

Alternatively, if there is a different or better way using `constant` or some other aspect of VHDL, please show me how.

Or just tell me that it can't be done, and if it is appropriate, please confirm that I could write functions to get and procedures to set the different subsets.

If I use functions and procedures, is there a cleaner notation than this? (I may need lots of this functions and procedures).

```
function get_temp_als(alarms : alarms_type)
  return alarms(sys1_temp_hi_al) & alarms(sys1_temp_lo_al) & alarms(sys2_temp_hi_al) & alarms(sys2_temp_lo_al);

function get_combined_temp_als(alarms : alarms_type)
  return alarms(sys1_temp_hi_al) or alarms(sys1_temp_lo_al) or alarms(sys2_temp_hi_al) or alarms(sys2_temp_lo_al);

procedure set_temp_als(alarms: alarm_type, value:std_logic)
begin
  alarms(sys1_temp_hi_al) <= value;
  alarms(sys1_temp_lo_al) <= value;
  alarms(sys2_temp_hi_al) <= value;
  alarms(sys2_temp_lo_al) <= value;;
end;
```

I would like this to work with VHDL 2002 and it is intended for synthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that aliases do not work like that. They are an alias to a single object (or slice thereof) and cannot be used to make new compounded objects like you might do with a pointer in another language.

A procedure is likely the only way you can achieve this. The alarms paramter should be a signal and mode out:

```
procedure set_temp_als(signal alarms: out alarm_type; value:std_logic)
begin
  alarms(sys1_temp_hi_al) <= value;
  alarms(sys1_temp_lo_al) <= value;
  alarms(sys2_temp_hi_al) <= value;
  alarms(sys2_temp_lo_al) <= value;
end;
```

so you can assign the alarms with:
`set_temp_als(alarms, '1');`

Your functions are the right idea, but syntactically wrong:

```
function get_temp_als(alarms : alarms_type) return std_logic_vector is
begin
  return alarms(sys1_temp_hi_al) & alarms(sys1_temp_lo_al) & alarms(sys2_temp_hi_al) & alarms(sys2_temp_lo_al);
end function;
```

```
signal some_other_slv : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

some_other_slv <= get_temp_als(alarms);
```

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are new names for existing named  entities not new entities.

> Alternatively, if there is a different or better way using constant or some other aspect of VHDL, please show me how.

There's the basic issue where it isn't clear what you're going to do with information, lacking a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you're trying to make more 'elegant'.

It is possible to use constants to specify alarms_type indexes:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity alarming is
end entity;

architecture fum of alarming is
    -- subprograms, constants and type declarations could be in a package
    subtype alarm_range is integer range 1 to 8;
    subtype alarms_type is std_logic_vector(alarm_range);
    signal alarms: alarms_type := (others => '0');

    constant sys1_temp_hi_al : integer := 1;
    constant sys1_temp_lo_al : integer := 2;
    constant sys1_crnt_hi_al : integer := 3;
    constant sys1_crnt_lo_al : integer := 4;
    constant sys2_temp_hi_al : integer := 5;
    constant sys2_temp_lo_al : integer := 6;
    constant sys2_crnt_hi_al : integer := 7;
    constant sys2_crnt_lo_al : integer := 8;

    type index is array (natural range <>) of alarm_range;

    constant  HI_ALARMS:  index := (sys1_temp_hi_al, sys1_crnt_hi_al,
                                    sys2_temp_hi_al, sys2_crnt_hi_al);

    constant  LO_ALARMS:  index := (sys1_temp_lo_al, sys1_crnt_lo_al,
                                    sys2_temp_lo_al, sys2_crnt_lo_al);

    constant TEMP_ALS:    index := (sys1_temp_hi_al, sys1_temp_lo_al, 
                                    sys2_temp_hi_al, sys2_temp_lo_al);

    constant CRNT_ALS:    index := (sys1_crnt_hi_al, sys1_crnt_lo_al, 
                                    sys2_crnt_hi_al, sys2_crnt_lo_al);

    constant SYS1_ALS:    index := (sys1_temp_hi_al, sys1_temp_lo_al,
                                    sys1_crnt_hi_al, sys1_crnt_lo_al);

    constant SYS2_ALS:    index := (sys2_temp_hi_al, sys2_temp_lo_al,
                                    sys2_crnt_hi_al, sys2_crnt_lo_al);

    function get_alarm (alarm: alarms_type; indx: alarm_range)
    return std_logic is
    begin
        return alarm(indx);
    end function;

    function set_alarm (alarm: alarms_type; indx: alarm_range)
    return alarms_type is
        variable ret_val:   alarms_type := alarm;
    begin
        ret_val(indx) := '1';
        return ret_val;
    end function;

    function get_alarms (alarm: alarms_type; alarm_indx: index) 
    return std_logic_vector is  -- doesn't look real useful.
        variable ret_val: std_logic_vector(alarm_indx'range);
    begin
        for i in alarm_indx'range loop
            ret_val(i) := alarm(alarm_indx(i));
        end loop;
        return ret_val;
    end function;

    -- instead:
    function select_alarms (alarm: alarms_type; alarm_indx: index)
    return alarms_type is
        variable ret_val: alarms_type := (others => '0');
    begin
        for i in alarm_indx'range loop
            ret_val(alarm_indx(i)) := alarm(alarm_indx(i));
        end loop;
        return  ret_val;
    end function;

    -- which returns a mask selected alarms_type value that allows the use of a
    -- single alarm service routine.


    function set_alarms (alarm: alarms_type; alarm_indx: index) 
    return alarms_type is
        variable ret_val: alarms_type := (others => '0');
    begin
        for i in alarm_indx'range loop
            ret_val(i) := alarm(alarm_indx(i));
        end loop;
        return ret_val;
    end function;

    procedure report_alarms (alarm: in alarms_type) is
        type name_array is array (alarm_range) of string (1 to 15);
        constant alarm_name:  name_array := ( 
              "sys1_temp_hi_al", "sys1_temp_lo_al",
              "sys1_crnt_hi_al", "sys1_crnt_lo_al",
              "sys2_temp_hi_al", "sys2_temp_lo_al",
              "sys2_crnt_hi_al", "sys2_crnt_lo_al"
        );
    begin
        for i in alarm_range loop
            if alarm(i) = '1' then
                report "alarm " & alarm_name(i) & " is set";
            end if;
        end loop;
    end procedure;

begin
    alarms <= select_alarms("11111111", TEMP_ALS) after 5 ns;
LABELED:
    process (alarms)
    begin
        report_alarms(alarms);
    end process;
end architecture;
```

And

```
ghdl -r alarming
alarming.vhdl:102:17:@5ns:(report note): alarm sys1_temp_hi_al is set
alarming.vhdl:102:17:@5ns:(report note): alarm sys1_temp_lo_al is set
alarming.vhdl:102:17:@5ns:(report note): alarm sys2_temp_hi_al is set
alarming.vhdl:102:17:@5ns:(report note): alarm sys2_temp_lo_al is set
```

tells us I can set all the temperature alarms using alarms selected by the set of temperature alarm indexes.

By providing a second parameter for selecting a set of alarms by name the number of subprograms drops (the alternative is to declare a type for all the different sets of alarms and provide subprograms for them all).

Comment: I like most of it.   Except report alarms since there is no correlation between the string names you are printing and the constant - other than you took care writing the package.   OTOH, if you changed the values sys1_temp_hi_al, ... to a value of an enumerated type, then you could fetch the name using to_string/ 'image.

Comment: The function report_alarms is illustrative. Note the names are all the same length. It wasn't clear if the code was intended for synthesis or not.  I'll email you a converted architecture (that uses enumerated type alarm_range and doesn't need to_string).

Comment: Yes, it is intended for synthesis.